# Premodifying adjectives and proper noun countability

Tags: adjectives, zero-article, proper-nouns, countability

> Secondhand PC hardware is incomparable with brand new Raspberry Pi.

In this sentence, is it correct to say *brand new Raspberry Pi* without making it countable? That is, *a brand new Raspberry Pi* or *brand new Raspberry Pis*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  It is not uncountable and therefore should be subjected to the normal rules of plurality (despite second-hand PC hardware being uncountable).

You can say:

> Secondhand PC hardware is incomparable with a brand new Raspberry Pi.

Or:

> Secondhand PC hardware is incomparable with brand new Raspberry Pis.

Admittedly, either is a little awkward, so you may consider rewording:

> Secondhand PC hardware is incomparable with *the* brand new Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I'm not sure about the reworded sentence though, by using the definite article _the_, aren't we refering to a specific Raspberry Pi model? Just like _the brand new iPhone_, which refers to the latest iPhone model in particular rather than all the iPhone models in general.

Comment: @skygate I think the "the" used here is a case of a singular noun representing a whole class, such as "The whale is a kind of mammal."  We're not talking about a specific raspberry pi, but all brand new rasberry pis.

Comment: I would use the "a brand new Raspberry Pi" version. In context there is no differentiation or indication of a specific unit. Also I don't know if "Raspberry Pis" is actually used. Non-technical folk might confuse it with raspberry pies...